# select date range to get insight of the page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API for getting insights of the page. For that I am using link like :

https://graph.facebook.com/MYPAGEID/insights/page_fans?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

This link gives me last three days of json object which is ok, but I want to specify date range in insights. I found end_date in documentation but not found start date.

Did any one know how I specify date range in this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the **since** and **until** parameters. For example:

https://graph.facebook.com/MYPAGEID/insights/page_fans?since=2011-01-01&until=2011-05-05&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

The only limitation is that you the range you specify cannot include be longer than about 35 days, otherwise you'll get this exception:

```
OAuthException
(#604) The specified date range cannot exceed 3024000 seconds"
```

Also see FB's own description of this using these parameters here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478