# In facebook select date range insights of the page using nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In nodes I am using the FB module for getting Graph API for getting insights on the page. For that i am giving request like

EX: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/12345_12345/insights?since=2014-12-01&until=2014-12-31

And I tried to manually hit in browser like

EX: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/12345_12345/insights?since=2014-12-01&until=2014-12-31&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

I refer following link and based on the instruction I tried some request, **but I am getting only empty data even it has a data.**

[select date range to get insight of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205161/select-date-range-to-get-insight-of-the-page) || [get insights data of facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814428/get-insights-data-of-facebook-page)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights
https://www.facebook.com/help/336893449723054

**NOTE**: 12345_12345 is page.data.id value here I gave duplicate value.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/posts.data.id/insights?since=2014-12-01&until=2014-12-31
```

To build the URL out of a variable (that's what I guess you want to do), you have to contruct it like this:

```
var pageId = posts.data.id;
var reqUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/' + pageId + '/insights?since=2014-12-01&until=2014-12-31';
...do http get request with reqUrl...
```

Comment: I know that here I just mentioned my request URL like this. In my code I gave which is you said manner.